# Using Javascript how to exchange the id of textbox

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

How can I exchange ids of two textboxes?

I have two textboxes,

```
<input type="text" id="name1" name="fname"/>
```

and

```
<input type="text" id="name2" name="lname"/>
```

programatically through Javascript, I want to exchange the ids **name1** and **name2** of both the textboxes. Please suggest the right way to achieve this.

Comment: This is do-able, but out of interest why would you do this? There might be a better way to achieve your end goal.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Getting a reference to the DOM elements? Getting the ID attributes? Setting the ID attributes?

Comment: I want to exchange the values of those text boxes. But both textboxes should contain the ids of each other so that it displays the value there opposite continuously. As it has many javascript events. I dont want to just exchange the values.

Comment: So... you don't want to switch the IDs of the elements? It gets more confusing... please update your question and state *clearly* what you want to do, together with a before and after example.

Answer (score 3):

```
function swapId( elem1, elem2 ) {
    var temp = elem1.id;
    elem1.id = elem2.id;
    elem2.id = temp;
}

swapId( document.getElementById('name1'), document.getElementById('name2') );
```

Which is a very simplified example. There should be more checking if passed in values really are references to actual DOM nodes etc. But this will work just fine.

Comment: I want to exchange the values of those text boxes. But both textboxes should contain the ids of each other so that it displays the value there opposite continuously. As it has many javascript events. I dont want to just exchange the values.

Answer (score 2):

Exchanging the IDs is as simple as getting a reference to the two text boxes, then assigning the IDs you want them to have. While it is invalid to temporarily have two elements with the same ID, no browser will prevent you from doing so.

```
var fname = document.getElementById('name1');
var lname = document.getElementById('name2');

fname.setAttribute('id', 'name2');
lname.setAttribute('id', 'name1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

```
var id1 = document.getElementById('name1');
var id2 = document.getElementById('name2');
id1.setAttribute("id", "name2");
id2.setAttribute("id", "name1");
```